# How is this matrix solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm moving a matrix to RREF, via the following steps (step by step, let me know if additional clarification is needed):

\begin{bmatrix}2&-2&3&|&2\\0&0&5&|&3\\-2&2&2&|&1\end{bmatrix}

divide by 2 to make the upper left = 1

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3/2&|&1\\0&0&5&|&3\\-2&2&2&|&1\end{bmatrix}

$R_3$ - (-2)*$R_1$

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3/2&|&1\\0&0&5&|&3\\0&0&5&|&2\end{bmatrix}

$R_3 / 5$

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3/2&|&1\\0&0&5&|&3\\0&0&1&|&2/5\end{bmatrix}

$R_2$ - 5 * $R_3$

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3/2&|&1\\0&0&0&|&1\\0&0&1&|&2/5\end{bmatrix}

$R_1$ - (3/2) * $R_3$

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&|&2/5\\0&0&0&|&1\\0&0&1&|&2/5\end{bmatrix}

At this point, as the middle row indicates 0 + 0 + 0 = 1, I expected that the matrix would be unsolvable. However in the book the solution is listed as

{(1/10, 3/5, 0), $\alpha(1,1,0)$, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$}

Am I performing one of my matrix operations incorrectly or am I misunderstanding when a matrix has no solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake in the second operation. The last cell should be 3 there:
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3/2&|&1\\0&0&5&|&3\\0&0&5&|&3\end{bmatrix}
Eventually you should arrive at
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&|&1/10\\0&0&1&|&3/5\\0&0&0&|&0\end{bmatrix}
from which the given result follows.